# UseInMemoryDatabase and preserve collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to cause items added into inmemory collection to be accessible immediately, like it would be with a normal db-backed DatabaseContext ?

```
// Init

var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
builder.UseInMemoryDatabase("my_in_memory");
this.InMemoryDbContext = new MyContext(builder.Options);

// Setup

InMemoryDbContext.SomeCollection.Add(itemOfMatchingType);

// Assert (1) --< it fails 
Assert.AreEqual(1, InMemoryDbContext.SomeCollection.Count());

// Another assert (2) <-- now it works
InMemoryDbContext.SaveChanges();
Assert.AreEqual(1, InMemoryDbContext.SomeCollection.Count());
```

Comment: What actually do you want to assert?

Answer (score 1):

Tested with SQLite and for latest EF Core the first assertion [fails](https://dotnetfiddle.net/wlIGP3) with db-backed DatabaseContext. If you want to assert what is added to current context you need to analyze `ChangeTracker`:

```
Assert.AreEqual(1, InMemoryDbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<MatchingType>().Count());
```

Comment: Thanks. I had an impression that with database-backed db this assertion doesn't fail.

Comment: @Alex glad if it has helped!